# General line integral when curl of vector field is nonzero

Tags: surface-integrals, line-integrals, curl

> Given $\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = (y-z,z-x,x-y)$, calculate the line integral $\int_C\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{l}$ where $C$ is any curve on the plane $x-z=1$.

My initial instincts to tackling this problem made me apply Stoke's theorem - calculating the curl of $\mathbf{F}$ we arrive at $-2\cdot(1,1,1)$ (ie curl is constant throughout all space and also on our plane $x-z=1$) which is most definitely nonzero and so the line integral will not be 0 either.

I then realised also that it is not specified that $C$ is a closed curve - so correct me if I'm wrong but it seems there is no way to solve this in the general case whatsoever?

Seems like a strange question I have been asked, since if it intends you to pick a curve yourself, and then integrate, you could simply pick an infinitesimal one and consequently call the whole thing 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the question should have been more clear.

We can apply Stokes' theorem if it is a closed curve. In case of a closed curve, we have $\displaystyle \int_C \vec F \cdot dr = \iint_S (\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \hat n \ dS \ $

The point to note is that the curve is in plane $x-z=1$ and unit normal vector to the plane is $\hat n = \frac{1}{\sqrt2} (1, 0, -1)$

So $(\nabla \times \vec F) \cdot \hat n = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}(-2, -2, -2) \cdot (1, 0, -1) = 0$

So for any closed curve in plane $x - z = 1$, the line integral will be zero.

If it is not a closed curve then yes we will have to know the curve and evaluate line integral.